# Renaming a list of variables using arrays in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to rename a list of variables by adding a suffix using arrays.  My code is as follows. I first generated the old and new variable lists as two arrays. Then, I looped over the list to rename each variable. I received the following error message. What is wrong? Thank you!

```
%let vars = tone1 tone2 tone3 fog reading kincaid flratio spec numint 
            uncert;
%let suffix = mda;

%put &vars;
%put &suffix;


 /*Generate the variable lists*//

proc transpose data=test(obs=0) out=names;
  var &vars;
run;



 proc sql noprint ;
   select _name_, cats(_name_,'_'&suffix)
   into :old_list separated by ' ', new_list separated by ' '
   from names; 
 quit;

%put &old_list;
%put &new_list;


data test;
  set test;
  array old[*] &old_list;
  array new[*] &new_list;
  do i=1 to dim(&old_list);
    rename old[i] = new[i];
   end;
 run;
```

I received the following error message:

```
1597  data test;
1598    set test;
1599    array old[*] &old_list;
1600    array new[*] &new_list;
1601    do i=1 to dim(&old_list);

NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "OLD_LIST".
1     Tone1 Tone2 Tone3 Fog Reading Kincaid FLRatio SPEC NumInt Uncert
        -----
        388
        76
1602      rename old[i] = new[i];
                -
                22
                76
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: -, :, =.

1603    end;
1604    run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DIM()` function needs an array name, not a list of variable names. The `RENAME` statement needs variable names, not array references.

Just generate the OLD=NEW pairs directly into one macro variable so you can use it in the RENAME statement.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select catx('=',_name_, cats(_name_,"_&suffix"))
    into :rename_list separated by ' '
    from names
  ; 
quit;

proc datasets nolist lib=work;
  modify test;
  rename &rename_list;
  run;
quit;
```

Answer (score 3):

`rename` is not a dynamic executable statement.  In other words, the data step at run-time can not add to or otherwise change the program data vector (pdv) that is built at automatic compilation-time.

You chose to subjugate TRANSPOSE to the role of just getting one row per var (interesting indeed) for data manipulation.

The end goal of just changing variable names is a metadata chore better suited to `Proc DATASETS`.  Rewriting an entire data set, just to change the column names can be ok with small data, but not a good idea for large data sets.

So the real task is to change a space separated list of tokens to a new list of items `<token>=<newtoken>` that can be used in a rename statement.

```
%let renamelist = %sysfunc(prxchange(s/(\w+)\b/$1=$1&SUFFIX/,-1,&VARS));
```

and

```
proc datasets nolist lib=work;
  modify test;
  rename &renamelist;
run; quit;
```

Comment: Never know SAS supports regular expression. Thank you!

Comment: Is `\b` really necessary? Words inside `VARS` are separated by a whitespace, so doesn't `(\w+)` already capture each single word?